# problem with Fmod wrapper (soundManager) for Ogre3d

Tags: c++, ogre3d, fmod, ogre

I have a problem with Soundmanager (class) (wrapper) for fmod in ogre3d engine. 
Here is the code just in case :

ISoundManager.h If somebody wants I will upload it but I can't upload more than 2 hyperlinks now.

SoundManager.h http://codeviewer.org/view/code:18c9

SoundManager.cpp http://codeviewer.org/view/code:18ca

I have a simple code piece to play the sound :

```
`   SoundManager *soundManagerPtr = new SoundManager;

    soundManagerPtr->Initialize();

    int mySound1 = soundManagerPtr->CreateStream(Ogre::String("boing.wav") );
    int channel1 = 0;

    soundManagerPtr->PlaySound(mySound1, headNode, &channel1);

    delete soundManagerPtr;`
```

Everything is fine, sound is loading, but PlaySound() function does not throw any error and does not play the sound either. I was asking on the ogre3d forum but no solution yet.

Comment: Ogre doesn't seem to use exceptions, but error codes. Maybe you can look whether an error gets logged?

Comment: @Polybos: Ogre DOES use exceptions. But it's probably the SoundManager that doesn't. I haven't looked at the CPP file yet.

Comment: @ViteFalcon I've looked at SoundManager at it doesnt.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the [links to codeviewer.org no longer work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345443/what-should-happen-to-questions-using-codeviewer-org-for-sharing-code). Without these links, the question has no clear [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the SoundManager needs to get updated and this is done by `frameStarted()`. This means for your sound to start playing you have to start running your Ogre application using `root->startRendering();`. Have you tried that? The above code is either incomplete (in which case you really do have a problem) or you just have to get the update of the SoundManager started off by starting the graphics to render and thus call frameStarted of SoundManager.

Answer (score 2):

I quickly checked the SoundManager code, and it appears the "PlaySound" function calls through to FMODs "playSound" function. In FMOD "playSound" is not a blocking operation, it will start playing the sound in another thread, then return. So since you are deleting the sound manager right away, it hasn't had a chance to play anything yet.

Comment: thanks for reply,
that was my problem. I removed the delete soundManagerPtr; line and everything works fine fine. I just have to put it somewhere else in the destructor and ... it should be fine :)